# How to include hours for the last day of the week in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing this query:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, vr_EmployeeLog.DateTimeStart), 0) period_start,
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, vr_EmployeeLog.DateTimeStart), 6) period_end 
FROM
    vr_EmployeeLog
```

I am getting the result:

```
period_start   2015-10-12 00:00:00.000
period end     2015-10-18 00:00:00.000
```

but I got records for period_end date 2015-10-18 01:56:00.000 AM and its not including in the result.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Comment: datetime column type

Comment: I need to use DateADD and DateDiff. where clause is not allowed for me

Answer (score 0):

Try using days instead of weeks.

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,vr_EmployeeLog.DateTimeStart),0) period_start,
    DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,vr_EmployeeLog.DateTimeStart),7) period_end         
FROM vr_EmployeeLog
```

But to choose data via a "date range" use a combination of greater than or equal to then less then (the next day)

```
SELECT *
FROM vr_EmployeeLog
WHERE vr_EmployeeLog.DateTimeStart >= '20151012'
AND vr_EmployeeLog.DateTimeStart < '20151019' --<< "the next day"
```

Do not be tempted to use "between" for this, always use >= and <

> the best practice with date and time ranges is to avoid BETWEEN and to
> always use the form:
>
> WHERE col >= '20120101' AND col < '20120201' This form works with all
> types and all precisions, regardless of whether the time part is
> applicable.

[Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-best-practices-part-2)

also

[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: I cannot use where clause for my query it should be DateAdd with DateDiff

Comment: the same holds true for a case expression; by the way how you should ask a question is to provide all constraints (like that comment) then supply  sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,DateTimeStart),0) period_start,
    DATEADD(day, 6, DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,DateTimeStart),0)) period_end
FROM vr_EmployeeLog

--ADD 6 days into period_start
```

Comment: you can use cast or convert to convert your result from datetime type to date type